# recursive promises won't execute

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

Well in a (trivial, I've move the actual load and replaced it by a time) piece of code I expect promises to happen recursive:

```
const all_related = [];
const createSub = async function(maxNum, depth) {
  if (depth > 0) {
    const n = 0;
    console.log(`depth: ${depth}`);
    const id = depth*maxNum +  n + 1;
    console.log(`id: ${id}`);
    try {
      const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 10, this);
      });
      await promise;
      all_related.push(id);
      console.log('after');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    createSub(maxNum, depth - 1);
  }
};
try {
  await createSub(1, 2);
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
console.log(all_related);
```

The function should be clear: it basically creates promises "based" on previous promises until it's run out of `depth`.

The final array (`all_related`) I expect to be `[3, 3]`. But furthermore I expect a log to be like:

```
depth: 2
id: 3
after
depth: 1
id: 2
after
[ 3, 2 ]
```

However the log I see is:

```
depth: 2
id: 3
after
depth: 1
id: 2
[ 3 ]
```

Also no error logging at all, nor any reports. - So this indicates that the second "depth" promise is not executed at all. - Why is this? The function is executed (I see `id: 2`), it just quits fully at the second promise.

Oh and how would I fix this?

Comment: Don't you need to have the "recursive" call be `await createSub(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not awaiting the recursive call, so the original completes before that one.

```
await createSub(maxNum, depth - 1);
```

Here's a demo:

```js
const all_related = [];
const createSub = async function(maxNum, depth) {
  if (depth > 0) {
    const n = 0;
    console.log(`depth: ${depth}`);
    const id = depth * maxNum + n + 1;
    console.log(`id: ${id}`);
    try {
      const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 10, this);
      });
      await promise;
      all_related.push(id);
      console.log('after');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    await createSub(maxNum, depth - 1);
  }
};
async function test() {
  try {
    await createSub(1, 2);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

test();
```

By the way, your call stack continues to grow with this approach, so you lose some of the benefit of async code. Not a big deal, but something to keep in mind.

Comment: I'll keep that hint in mind - though this code is basically a setup for an integration test (populating a db and creating link between those), so not meant to be optimized.